# Use of Uri.parse or Uri.file

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, audio-player, just-audio

** Hi i want to use my asset image on screen while playing any song but im able to use oniline image but not asset image how to use asset image?**

````
      Uri.parse("live url"),
      tag: MediaItem(
        id: '${_nextMediaId++}',
        album: "Punjab1Radio",
        title: "Punjab1Radio Live",
        artUri: Uri.file('assets/logo.png'),
      ),
    ),```
````

Comment: does it work ? I have the same issues.

Comment: I have given solutions on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75456939/how-to-show-artmusic-on-media-control-notification-from-assets-file-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `pubspec.yaml` and  remove the comment from asset dependency and chang the asset path to your asset path

Comment: Please expalain in detail with example.

Comment: Parsing uri.file will take file path so assets should be added in pubspec yaml and if you want to import that file same path should be passed in pubspec yaml

Comment: Yes @AshwaniBhardwaj I have written a solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75456939/how-to-show-artmusic-on-media-control-notification-from-assets-file-in-flutter