# How to show artMusic on Media control (Notification) from assets file in flutter

Tags: flutter, media-player, audio-player, just-audio, flutter-audioplayers

I am using ***Just Audio*** and ***Just Audio Background*** for playing music and media control on Notification.

I am able to show album, title of storage songs on Notification control but unable to show ***artmusic*** of music on Notification.

I am using [on Audio query](https://pub.dev/packages/on_audio_query) for fetching device music list and displaying in list.

```
 player.value.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(
         Uri.parse(uri),
         tag: MediaItem(
           // Specify a unique ID for each media item:
           id: id.toString(),
           // Metadata to display in the notification:
           album: album.toString(),
           title: title.toString(),
           artUri: Uri.parse("https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg"),
         ),
       ));
```

I am able to parse any http url of image but unable parse asset image file path in artMusic .
Kindly suggest any solutions.

Comment: There's a feature request with a workaround: https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/523#issuecomment-730341353

Comment: @SePröbläm Thanks for your help . I was looking this solutions . It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issues in this way.

```
 sources.add(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(song.uri!),
          tag: MediaItem(
            // Specify a unique ID for each media item:
            id: song.id.toString(),
            // Metadata to display in the notification:
            album: song.album.toString(),
            title: song.title.toString(),
            artist: song.artist.toString(),
            artUri: await  getImageFileFromAssets() ,
          )));
```

Now create a method **getImageFileFromAssets()** and pass the path of assets images.

```
 Future<Uri> getImageFileFromAssets() async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/music.png');
    final buffer = byteData.buffer;
    Directory tempDir =  await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var filePath =
        tempPath + '/file_01.png'; // file_01.tmp is dump file, can be anything
    return (await File(filePath).writeAsBytes(
        buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes)))
        .uri;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post this function getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider use this i answered my own question