# how to set Just audio backgroud notification audio artwork using the local audio file image uri = content://

Tags: flutter, plugins, just-audio, pub.dev

So I am trying to display an audio artwork in the notification panel on Android, but I don't seem to know how to get it to work out right.

In the example on the [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background) site, it used an image URL for the notification artwork, and this was the code it used:

```
AudioSource.uri(
  Uri.parse('https://example.com/song1.mp3'),
  tag: MediaItem(
    // Specify a unique ID for each media item:
    id: '1',
    // Metadata to display in the notification:
    album: "Album name",
    title: "Song name",
    artUri: Uri.parse('https://example.com/albumart.jpg'),
  ),
),
```

The artUti is getting the image from an online site, but in my case, I am trying to get it from a local audio file, for which the image link is similar to this ***content://data/...***

I have really tried to debug it, but it is not working out fine for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question title to mention the `content://` URI? That's the key thing that differentiates your question, but your question title actually reads as more generic so people who search for this question might be surprised that your question doesn't actually match your title.

Comment: @RyanHeise i have done that, can you asset me with the answer to the question

Comment: First, can you try the songs example in audio_service? https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/minor/audio_service/example/lib/example_android_songs.dart

Comment: @MichaelStephen kindly check this . I was also facing the same issues and resolves in this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75456939/how-to-show-artmusic-on-media-control-notification-from-assets-file-in-flutter

Comment: Hi @RahulKushwaha, am sorry for the late reply, I will check it out and see if it works out, I kinda dished the project cus of this issue and I am currently learning Kotlin, guessed it could have been easier with Kotlin.

Comment: @MichaelStephen it will surely works .

Comment: **First, can you try the songs example in audio_service?**
Thanks this work just fine